# Android vision - Face, glasses and cap detection

Tags: android, version-control, face-detection

I am using Android `com.google.android.gms.vision` library to detect Faces on camera pictures. It works quite well for detecing faces ane eyes but I am missing

1. Glasses/sunglasses
2. Cap/headger

detection features. Any hints what should I use? OpenCV or maybe are there any additional packages to Android Vision library?

Thanks